# Function struct array input cin problems

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

I can't figure out how to fix this code.

```
void getInfo(Author a[], int size)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the author's name: ";
            getline(cin, a[x].name);

            if(a[x].name == "NONE")
                break; //Breaks the loop if the author has no further books
            else

            for(int y = 0; y < size; y++)
                {
                    cout << "Enter title " << y+1 << " :";
                    getline(cin, a[x].book[y].title);

                    if(a[x].book[y].title == "NONE")
                        break;
                    else
                        cout << "Enter price " << y+1 << " :  $"; 
                        cin >> a[x].book[y].price;
                }
            cout << endl;
        }
}
```

This is how it is compiling:

```
Get user's input:
Enter the author's name: John Smith
Enter title 1: How to Tie a Shoe
Enter price 1: 20
Enter title 2: Enter price 2:
```

Could someone please help me understand how to fix this loop. When I try a `getline(cin, a[x].book[y].price);` ,visual studio tells me that it is overloaded.

Comment: Try `cin.ignore(1,'\n');` after you read the price. And maybe try some braces around that else block, or better still get rid of the else entirely (the one in the for-loop)

Comment: try `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')`. reads as many charactes till you get '\n' and discards it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, use [`cin.ignore();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) after `cin >>`.

[`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) accepts a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for its second parameter.

It think you're passing a numerical variable to it by `getline(cin, a[x].book[y].price);`.

Comment: @bash.d its in his list sentence of the question.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Regarding your comment, I tested it and it doesn't work well but `ignore()` overload works fine! :-D